# Удаление определенного сегмента в строке

Tags: строки, cmd, bat, редактор

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh > 1.txt
sort < 1.txt 
pause
```

мне надо, чтоб осталось только название и занимаемую память процессоров так, что сортировка была по названию , а где одинаковое название по памяти.

Comment: Найти для винды и использовать [cut - remove sections from each line of files](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

Comment: @avp, тогда уж лучше [sed](https://github.com/mbuilov/sed-windows)

Comment: @gregzakharov, почему? `cut -b -5,11- file.txt` влет решает задачу

Comment: @ avp не работает 
 ' @echo off
tasklist > pr.txt
cut -b -25,63- pr.txt 
sort < pr.txt 
start pr.txt
pause '

Comment: @ZhoskiY,  в \*nix-ах `cut` выводит (как и большинство команд) свой результат в stdout (а не редактирует файл (думаю в винде он работает так же))  Попробуйте `tasklist |  cut -b -25,63-  | sort >pr.txt`

Comment: Я так понимаю по сути вопроса -  это дубль раннего сообщения [... столбик выравнивался по правой стороне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/901575/) Метод решения и того, и этого вопроса одинаков. Значит данный вопрос - дубль.

Comment: @avp пишет cut не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: @avp в гит баше работает. Мне ещё надо для cmd сделать, но команды cut там нет

Comment: Добрые люди вроде бы (я не проверял) сделали портинг [CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)

Comment: @avp Мне надо без других утилит сделать. Так как мне показывать надо будет на другом пк

Comment: @ZhoskiY, тогда  или переходите программировать в \*nix-ы или ждите, когда какой-либо знаток винды вам подcкажет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh >list.txt
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
( for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2,3*" %%a in (list.txt) do (
set "A=%%a 
set B=%%d 
echo !A:~0,30!!B:~1,15!
) ) > t2.txt
sort t2.txt > t3.txt
endlocal
start t3.txt
```